# RecyclerView is not displaying database contents as expected

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Here's the data in my database:

[image: Here's the data in my database]

Here's the code of my project. I found no error. It is not displaying the contents in it, even it is showing a blank page.

Adapter

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MylistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MylistAdapter.MylistViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<RequestUser> users;


    class MylistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView dispname1;
        private TextView dispphn1;
        private TextView dispcity1;
        private TextView dispaddr1;
        private TextView dispnumber1;

        private MylistViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            dispaddr1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispaddr);
            dispcity1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispcity);
            dispname1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispname);
            dispphn1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.disphn);
            dispnumber1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispnumber);
        }
    }


    public MylistAdapter(ArrayList<RequestUser> usrs) {
        this.users= usrs;
    }


    @Override
    public MylistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
        MylistViewHolder mlvh=new MylistViewHolder(v);
        return mlvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MylistViewHolder holder, int position) {

        RequestUser curuser=users.get(position);

        holder.dispphn1.setText(curuser.getRphn1());
        holder.dispname1.setText(curuser.getRname1());
        holder.dispcity1.setText(curuser.getRcity1());
        holder.dispaddr1.setText(curuser.getRaddr1());
        holder.dispnumber1.setText(curuser.getRnumber1());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }
}
```

Main Class

Which contains the main functionality

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Transport extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference dbreferance;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private ArrayList<RequestUser> usrs=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transport);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreferance= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Donate");
        dbreferance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                usrs.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot child:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    //String id=child.getKey();
                    RequestUser usr=child.getValue(RequestUser.class);
                    usrs.add(usr);
                    //RequestUser usr= (RequestUser) child.getValue();
                    //usrs.add(usr);
                    //System.out.println(usr.rname1);
                    Toast.makeText(Transport.this,usr.getRphn1(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapter=new MylistAdapter(usrs);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


}
```

XML Layouts

for the Recycler view and the card views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Line1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispcity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dispname"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Line2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispaddr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dispcity"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Line3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/disphn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dispaddr"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Line4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dispnumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dispaddr"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Line5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Another Layout

ie for card view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Transport">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Yes I posted right now can you please help

Comment: Please also add the content of your `RequestUser` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we add listener Android create a separate thread for that and that thread run separately. So in your case we you are adding the listener android is creating the separate thread for that and then it immediately set the adapter for the recyclerView.

Create the adapter before adding the listener and set the adapter with recyclerView in the `onDataChanged( )` method after the for loop.

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            usrs.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot child:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                //String id=child.getKey();
                RequestUser usr=child.getValue(RequestUser.class);
                usrs.add(usr);
                //RequestUser usr= (RequestUser) child.getValue();
                //usrs.add(usr);
                //System.out.println(usr.rname1);
                Toast.makeText(Transport.this,usr.getRphn1(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```